# Winrt Xaml Grid ROw not filling Space with *

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have the problem, that my Grid is not filling the space as I want it.
Here some code:

```
<HubSection>
      <Grid  Width="850">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="310"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Input:RadDatePicker Grid.Row="0" Value="{Binding CurrentDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                   <ListView 
                            Grid.Row="1">...
                   </ListView>
                   <Grid Height="310"
                            Grid.Row="2">...
                   </Grid>
```

...
I want that the middle row is filling the space up of the hubsection. Instead it now just fills up when the listview contains enough items.
Any idea?

[image: Screen with a few ListViewItems. Notice the empty bottom]

Now the filled ListView:
[image: Screen with a filled ListView - Scrollbar is visible. Bottom is filled.]

Comment: Incomplete. What do you see, how is the Height of the Grid determined?

Comment: As I described. The grid is only 35+310 px + height of the listview. The ListView is not extended to remaining height. No grid height given. Putting Grid.Height="Auto" does not help.

Comment: Still not complete. Is there something in Row="2" that you can see, does it flow to the bottom?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Row 2 does NOT flow to the bottom as that is my goal. VerticalAlign="bottom" does not help either.
Row 1 is not expanding to fill the space completely - if only a few ListItems are there.

Comment: Somethin I found: if I set the Grid Height to a fixed space - the ListView is correctly filling up the space (*). Unfortunately I don't know the height. Probably only possible via ugly code behind magic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` of the `HubSection` to `Stretch` as well as setting the VCA of the outer grid to that option. I'm suspecting the default might be `Center` or `Top` and so the minimizing vertical alignment control from the parent control and the expanding star-sized row setting of the inner grid come in a little bit of a conflict that some layout prioritizing rules probably resolve in getting the VCA rule to win.

For similar layout issues it is usually best to analyze with a visual tree debugger such as the XAML Spy or WinRT XAML Toolkit. You can also try tracing these various properties by walking the visual tree with the `VisualTreeHelper` class yourself.

Comment: That hint with the VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" was it. So simple :)